# How to bring the algorithm straight after the paragraph

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I am trying to start my algorithm right after a small paragraph, instead of starting it from the next page. I have tried numerous way, e.g. change float to "h!" or "H", but to no avail. Can someone help me?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, openright,titlepage,fleqn,%
              headinclude,footinclude,BCOR5mm,%
              numbers=noenddot,cleardoublepage=empty]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

The following is some random algorithm.

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{: (optimization procedure}
\label{alg:cmaes}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]

\Procedure{(1+1)-CMA-ES } {n, m, z, i}
    \State Check the initial or existing iteration parameters.
    
\If{$i = 0$}  \Comment{If it is the start of iteration, use initial parameters.}
        \State $\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{x}_0$ \Comment{Parental var., shape = (n, 1)}
        \State $\boldsymbol{\sigma} = \boldsymbol{\sigma}_0$  \Comment{e.g.: 0.5}
        \State $\boldsymbol{A} = I$  \Comment{(n, n)}
\EndIf
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

To give you some image, the following is the result (using the real script, different from the MWE):
[image: As you can see, the algorithm starts at the next page instead of right after the paragraph.]

For some reason, the algorithm start from a fresh (next) page. Can I do something to bring the algorithm right after the paragraph (start from the same page as the paragraph)?

Comment: Compile your example and in output pdf I get text and algorithm on the same page. Your example can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ ah I see....turns out it waa because my algorithm was too long to be put in the same page, I had to break it down to "smaller pieces". Now it is working. Thank you.